# Rebol and oAuth: how to?

Tags: rebol

There are a bunch of samples in other programming languages but none for rebol.

How would I do the equivalent of this C# sample:

http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/codingthetweet

or this in php

http://www.snipe.net/2009/07/writing-your-first-twitter-application-with-oauth/

Comment: Both of those tutorials use a pre-built oAuth library. if you can find a Rebol oAuth library or link Rebol against non-Rebol code then you might be able to use one of those - libraries at http://oauth.net/code/ Or you'll have to code your own Rebol oAuth library.

Comment: i think i'll have to look at oauth in details then :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.ross-gill.com/page/Twitter_API_and_REBOL

for an implementation of OAuth.

Comment: I have written a cURL-based REST protocol that supports OAuth here: http://reb4.me/r/rest-curl — An alternate, specific REBOL OAuth protocol lives here: http://reb4.me/r/oauth

Answer (score 0):

You may write your own protocol:

"An open protocol to allow secure API authorization in a simple and standard method from desktop and web applications."
http://oauth.net/

"The OAuth 1.0 Protocol"
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849

Comment: I'm not capable of even understanding how protocol works in rebol even less write one. That's one of the reason most people even developer used to languages like php cannot find rebol worth in real use. And I'm not even a developer :)

Comment: Protocols are one of the most versatile aspects of REBOL.  You don't have to build a multi-storey behemoth such as HTTP - it can be a small wrapper that takes advantage of REBOL's url handling and series natives.  PHP could only dream of such a clean and unobtrusive extension to it's vocabulary...